# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: easy-autocomplete/dist/easy-autocomplete

Tags: ruby, toastr, easyautocomplete

i want to install ruby website on my machine but i have this probleme hwo can help me

[image]

Comment: How did you install this `easy-autocomplete` lib ? Do you have a link to the repo ?

Comment: I have installed a website created on ruby on my computer , and i have no idea how the website works, because I want to learn through it (sorry for my english).